# ksh + smart test line solution

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I 
write the following syntax (part  of my ksh script)
to check if the first word of LINE=star 
and the second word is car

```
     [[ ` echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}' ` = star  ]] && [[  ` echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}' ` = car  ]] && print "match"
```

I need other simple smart and shorter solution then my syntax. 
from awk,perl or sed(if it possible to use echo only once or better if we cant not use echo, because I need to save time to minimum)
can I get some ideas?

Comment: If performance is that much of an issue, perhaps ksh is the wrong choice for your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't actually need to call any external tools

```
set -f 
set -- $LINE
case "$1 $2" in 
 "star car") 
    echo "match";;
esac
```

Comment: @ghostdog74: This will sometimes match when it shouldn't, e.g., with `LINE='star *'`. It would work if you did `set -f` first, to turn off glob expansion on the unquoted substitution of `$LINE` (and even that is fragile if you change the searched strings, because some backslashes are always expanded in unquoted substitutions).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an external process at all:

```
[[ $LINE == *([ ])star+([ ])car?([ ]*) ]]
```

If you also need to extract the first word sometimes (warning, typed directly into the browser):

```
LINE=${LINE##+[ ]}  # strip leading spaces
first_word=${LINE%%[ ]*}
if [[ $LINE = *[ ]* ]]; then
  LINE_minus_first_word=${LINE##*+([ ])}
else
  LINE_minus_first_word=''
fi
```

Add a tab inside the brackets if they may appear in `$LINE`.

Comment: You should mention that these require `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: I should have said "...for Bash" since they are always on for ksh.

Answer (score 1):

```
set -o noglob
words=($LINE)
[[ "${words[0]} ${words[1]}" == "star car" ]] && print "match"
```

**Edit:**

Using ksh and Bash's regex matching (Bash >= version 3.2):

```
pattern='^[[:blank:]]*star[[:blank:]]+car([[:blank:]]+|$)'
[[ $LINE =~ $pattern ]] && print "match"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
[[ ` echo $LINE | awk '{printf("%s:%s",$1,$2)}'` = star:car ]] && print "match"
```

Comment: same problem as [ghostdog74](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563349/ksh-smart-test-line-solution/3563752#3563752), plus calling awk contradicts the speed requirement in the question.